# jQuery blur not triggering arrow functions inside a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, arrow-functions

I'm new to JS classes and the fat arrow syntax. I read all I can but still can't figure out why are my functions not triggering. I know for sure the blur is happening on the inputs1-3, from console.logs I know the selector is ok, but still the console.log in validateForm() never gets triggered. What am I missing?

```
class FreezingScan {

constructor(parentElement) {
    this.parentElement = $(parentElement);
    console.log(this.parentElement);
    let subItems = $(parentElement).children(".scanSubItems");
    this.row1 = $(parentElement).children(".scanInput1");
    this.row2 = $(subItems).children(".scanInput2");
    this.row3 = $(subItems).children(".scanInput3");
    this.input1 = $(this.row1).children('input');
    this.input2 = $(this.row2).children('input');
    this.input3 = $(this.row3).children('input');
    this.clearBindEvents();
    this.bindEvents();
}

clearBindEvents() {
    this.input1.unbind();
    this.input2.unbind();
    this.input3.unbind();
}

bindEvents() {
    $(this.input1).blur(() => { this.validateForm() });
    $(this.input2).blur(() => { this.validateForm() });
    $(this.input3).blur(() => { this.validateForm() });
}

validateForm() { console.log('validated')  }
```

Comment: Why do you unbind first?

Comment: @onetwo12 So all previously binded events are unbinded. I already tried it without it, the result was exactly the same, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Can you create an [mcve] that *demonstrates the problem*?  Perhaps your HTML is not how you expect it to be?  It works fine for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/x3dvqaru/

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: Adding logging in `bindEvents` to find out if `this.input1` is what you think it is would probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the fat arrow syntax it changes the scope of the keyword `this` to be the parent scope and not of your function. You will either need to use the `function` key word instead or update to your to code to look at the target of the current event. Something like this:

```
bindEvents() {
    $(this.input1).blur((event) => { $(event.currentTarget).validateForm() });
    $(this.input2).blur((event) => { $(event.currentTarget).validateForm() });
    $(this.input3).blur((event) => { $(event.currentTarget).validateForm() });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, then I misunderstood what the scope is. I wanted the arrow functions to see the scope of the whole class. I will have to use normal functions then.

Comment: "When you use the fat arrow syntax it changes the scope of the keyword this to be the parent scope and not of your function." — Since `validateForm` is a mathod on the parent scope … that's desirable here! `event.currentTarget` will be the HTML element that has blurred, not the `FreezingScan` with the `validateForm` method on it.